# Automated login office 365 outlook

Tags: c#, outlook

I have a c# mvc application which has login functions with username and password same as sts ( this is not sts login and it does not login sts too). However now I want to use this login information to login to office 365 outlook which means once the user login to my mvc application they will be able to directly access outlook through a link without login again. How can I do this? I have searched office 365 api but it does not fit to my usage as I am not requesting any data but login.

I will elaborate more.

**Background**: currently our organization is using office 365 services and I think we already integrate with ADFS login which we can login the office 365 service ( in this case outlook) at `https://sts.xxx.com/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignin1.0&.....`

**What we want to do**: we are currently building an application in which logged in users will no longer need to go the url above to login outlook. As long as they logged in our application, they are able to access the outlook through a normal link for example `<a href="outlook address">Go outlook</a>` and they can start checking their mails.

**What we tried**: we tried using offie 365 api but I dont think that this is the right way as we are not retriving any data from the api except we want to use our application login information to login office 365

Answer (score 2):

If your Outlook servers are ADFS integrated, then you need to host your code on a server (HTTPS enabled) and integrate it with same ADFS. Once the users are logged into ADFS, they dont need to login again.

Comment: we are using another login system, can we login ADFS remotely

Comment: Once you login to ADFS, it sets a cookie in your browser so next and further requests to AFDS will not need the user to authenticate again. So if your application is ADFS integrated, then further redirects from your page to Outlook will not take the user to login page again